# Output from logger.info have question mark (?) if log format have multiple spaces

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I am using org.slf4j in my module for logging purpose. I have encountered an interesting problem in my log file in production environment.

```
logger.info("Updating  user {} ", uuid);
```

output for this line =>

```
Updating? user 06XXXXd5-bXX4-4XX2-9XX7-f9XXXXXXXXb6
```

I have checked my code version, check for any special character, environment difference, Java version difference etc. But all looks same and correct.

Can someone advise me how to check this issue?

Comment: What's the effective logging system below SLF4J?  Check its cfg file.

Comment: <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>

Answer (score 2):

As per code `logger.info("Updating  user {} ", uuid);` question mark coming in between string `Updating? user 06XXXXd5-bXX4-4XX2-9XX7-f9XXXXXXXXb6` so there may be a chance of special character in string. kindly check if there is any special character exist in `"Updating  user {} "` string.(remove and rewrite string ..do not copy paste)

Comment: I checked for special characters in different IDEs and Terminal. But no luck. It is just space.

Comment: try another text eg- "logger.info("this is testing");" and check question mark coming or not.

Comment: No it's not coming.

Comment: So might be an issue with your string.